# Hosting model on amazon aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have pre-trained model in Keras.I want to host the model on Amazon AWS for real-time prediction. Can someone list the steps to do this. I am very new to this.How to deploy my model for predictions?

Answer (score 0):

You could package your own pre-trained algorithms by "containerizing" the algorithm via Docker. This documentation page will guide you through how to package your algorithm into a Docker image in Elastic Container Service: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms.html

You may then directly deploy your packaged algorithm via SageMaker Hosting. This is a three-step process: CreateModel -> CreateEndpointConfig -> CreateEndpoint. Here's the documentation about how to host your packaged algorithm on SageMaker: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-hosting.html

Cheers,
Yuting